# NewRelicAgent_ios_5.0.1 does not support xcode 7.0?

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform

I downloaded latest xcode version and tried running my existing code.I got this:

/Frameworks/NewRelicAgent.framework/NewRelicAgent(NRGCDOverride.o)' does not contain bit-code. You must rebuild it with bit-code enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bit-code for this target. for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have updated the latest code for newrelic (if only xcode 7 compatible) : use https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/release-notes/mobile-release-notes/ios-release-notes/ios-530

otherwise to make it compatible for xcode 6 too use: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/release-notes/mobile-release-notes/ios-release-notes/ios-agent-522